# How to read project properties defined in boom by java?

Tags: java, maven

I have properties file and I told maven to read from it and add it to the project properties.
I would like to access those properties from java in runtime.

What is the best way to acomplish that?
*I noticed that `System.getProperty("myPropertyName") == null` beacuse I'm not trying to read java system properties. Am I currect?

**pom:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>my-app</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>initialize</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <files>
                            <file>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/bo.properties</file>
                        </files>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Comment: Maven is used to build your program. When you run the program, it has no idea it has been built by Maven, and doesn't care if properties were loaded into the Maven build or not. What is your code, what does your jar file contain, what do you expect this code to do and what does it do instead?

Comment: I dont have any code yet, Only an empty main method. So what is the point of project properties in maven if one can not access it in runtime? And what is the best way to write some properties in diffrent file and accessing them thought the code?

Comment: *I would like to access those properties from java in runtime*: an empty main method won't do that. Just remove this properties-maven-plugin. Maven **by default** adds everything under src/main/resources to the classpath of the project (i.e. to the built jar), and you can then load the resource using Class.getResource[AsStream](). The point of loading properties in a Maven build is to be able to use these properties during the build.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replay. You did answer my question. In other context, What do you mean by "Maven by defualy adds everything under src/main/resources to the classpath of the project"? Do you mean only the path: "src/main/resources" ? If I have folders or jars there, does they will be added too? Can you please reference/give an example as an answer? Thanks for all the help!

Comment: No. My wording was not very precise. What I meant is that all the files, recursively, locates in src/main/resources end up in the target/classes directory, with the .class files, and are later bundled inside the generated jar file with the .class files. So these resources can be loaded using the ClassLoader at runtime.